# SVN - Delete existing repository

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I made the mistake of modifying my original source after importing it into subversion.  I now need to re-import but get a "File already exists:".  How can I most cleanly remove my existing repository and add it back?

Comment: Which SVN Tool are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just checkin the modifications as a change? That's what svn is for.

---

If you really want to replace the version in there, you can delete it first, then re-add. But, the original version will be available if you walk back in time (again, that's what svn is for). If you want to destroy the history, I'd just recreate the repo. This is the only sane way to restart the revision number, especially for beginners.

Seriously, though, there's nothing wrong with checking in a bunch of revisions as your get your source code cleaned up.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. There is nothing shameful in having a high revision number in your SVN.